# DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn CellMouseClick

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am using a `DataGridView` which contains a `CheckBox` column. When I try to retrieve the value of that column, it is always false. Please let me know the reason.

Here is my code:

```
private void dataGridViewCrossRef_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
     {
       bool isChecked1 = false;
       isChecked1 = (Boolean)dataGridViewCrossRef[25, e.RowIndex].FormattedValue;
       if (isChecked1)
       {
          //Some code
       }
     }
```

Comment: What are the items of the `ComboBox`, just a "True" or "False"?

Comment: Sorry its not combobox its a checkbox ...

Comment: try my answer, let me know if you have found some errors. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Try the `CellContentClick Event`

```
    private void dataGridViewCrossRef_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 25)
        {
            bool IsBool = false;
            if (bool.TryParse(dataGridViewCrossRef[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].EditedFormattedValue.ToString(), out IsBool))
            {
               //Some code
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

Try this in `CellClick Event` and you need to declare your `dataTable` as a `public`

```
   private void dataGridViewCrossRef_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 25)
        {
            //Find primaykey or something unique from your dataTable   
            DataRow[] Rows = dataTable.Select("Id = '" + dataGridViewCrossRef[0, e.RowIndex].EditedFormattedValue.ToString() + "'");

            Rows[0]["NameOfColumnHasCheckBox"] = !bool.Parse(Rows[0]["NameOfColumnHasCheckBox"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: dataGridViewCrossRef[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = !(bool)dataGridViewCrossRef[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;

Comment: Sorry but still the result of bool is false only

Comment: how did you bind your `Data` to `DataGridView`? by `BindingSource` or `DataTable` or unbound data?

Comment: hold on again, next time in your question just add some important details from your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

As the Data Bound to the Chekbox is integer so the i have change the code as bellow and it worked.

Thanks

private void dataGridViewCrossRef_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 25)
            {
                int CellValue = 0;
                CellValue = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridViewCrossRef[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].EditedFormattedValue);
                if (CellValue == 1)
                {

```
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: try to edit your question :), this is must be your question. i will modify my answer, just hold on.